# iTunes 11 sort issue - tracks in album view

Tags: itunes-11

I recently updated to iTunes 11 (pc version), and everything seems to be working except for the order of tracks in the album view. My problem is that it seems to put the songs in a random order, rather than sorting them alphabetically. However, when set to play the album, it plays alphabetically. So I have a situation where I can't find any of my songs, and I can't follow the playing order either!
I know that you can force a sort order using track numbers, but manually adding track numbers based on alphabetical order seems **very** time-consuming. Is there an easier way? Does anyone know why iTunes sorts tracks in that order?
Thank you in advance if you are able to be of assistance.

Comment: *I know that you can force a sort order using track numbers* Songs on an album ARE ordered by track numbers???

Comment: Most of my music doesn't have track numbers, and I've become acustomed to finding songs by name (alphabetical order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a tool like MP3Tag, which can do bulk updates to the tags in your music collection - including setting track numbers.